# Dynamically and conditionally adding columns to view

Tags: sql-server

I have the following view in SQL Server 2014:

```
CREATE VIEW sales_snapshot 
AS
    SELECT
        sdb.sku,
        sdb.district,
        sdb.num_units,
        sdb.location
    FROM 
        sales_db as sdb
GO
```

What I would like to do, is add additional columns, where the column name is `location_stock` and the value would be `sdb.num_units`.

For instance, if `location = 'headquarters'` then the column name `headquarters_stock` would be added to the view, and the value would be `sdb.num_units`. This would be if the column does not exist.

**Edit**: if this cannot be done dynamically, and I add the column names:

```
headquarters
new_york
ohio
```

How would I fill the right column with data, based on the value of sdb.location?

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Just permanently add the columns but only select them when you need them. There is no way to dynamically add/remove columns.

Comment: Please see edit. How would I do this conditionally as part of the select statement?

Comment: But why do you need a different column per location? This is an app/client code problem. Just change the header in your display code based on the location provided?

Comment: But if you really have to do it that way, just use `case when location = '' then stock else 0 end` and change the location for each column.

Comment: What is your version of SQL Server? There is no such thing as SQL Server 2015.

Comment: @Alex Make that 2014

Comment: You can try creating a table valued function with a IF condition. Have 2 sets of Select based on if condition is true or false.

Comment: The answer to the edit is "conditional aggregation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to dynamically add columns to a view, even if there was it would cause problems down the line for queries using said views due to references to missing columns etc.

If you have a fixed number of locations known in advance, then you can use [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
CREATE VIEW sales_snapshot AS
    -- If you want column names changed e.g headquarters_stock, then you should do it here
    SELECT sdb.sku, db.district, [headquarters] AS [headquarters_stock], [new_york], [ohio]
    FROM
        -- If you have an empty (or NULL) location, you would need to assign
        -- a default non empty value to it e.g.
        -- ISNULL( NULLIF( sdb.location, '' ), 'empty' ) AS [location]
        ( SELECT sdb.sku, sdb.district, sdb.num_units, sdb.location
        FROM sales_db as sdb ) AS SourceT
    PIVOT(
        SUM( num_units ) FOR [location] IN( [headquarters], [new_york], [ohio] )) AS PivotT;
```

If locations change dynamically then you would need to implement a [dynamic PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query). As views cannot have dynamic SQL in them, you would need to add logic to dynamically re-create/alter view when a new location is added / removed. Unless you have a very good reason for it and you know what you are doing, I would not recommend using a view in this scenario.

Comment: This got me in the right direction. Normally I do this via application code not SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a dynamic columns in a view.But to answer the "Edit Part" of your question, you can use a case statement in your view.

```
CREATE VIEW sales_snapshot AS
SELECT
    sdb.sku,
    sdb.district,
    sdb.num_units,
    sdb.location,
    CASE WHEN sdb.location='headquarters' THEN sdb.num_units ELSE NULL END as headquarters_stock
FROM sales_db as sdb
GO
```

Syntax for a CASE with multiple conditions goes like this

```
CASE 
WHEN alphabet='a' THEN 'Amy'
WHEN alphabet='b' THEN 'Boyd'
ELSE "Zia"
END as "new_column_name"
```